# Conditional selects from a table using another SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a bit of difficulty on how to set up this dynamic conditional select statement.

I've whittled it down to this basic premise:

I have two tables, table 1 is `Cars`:

```
   Id  Serial  Size
   1    x99     M
   2    x99     L
   3    z50     M
   4    x99     S
```

and table two is a `CodeAssignment` table:

```
   Id  Serial  Size  Code
   1    x99     L    5000
   2    x99    NULL  3000
   3    z50    NULL   60
```

I'm trying to get a statement that will pull the following:

```
   Id  Serial  Size  Code
   1    x99     M    3000
   2    x99     L    5000
   3    z50     M     60
   4    x99     S    3000
```

Where the Code is pulled as a default (i.e. where the `Size` is `NULL` on the `CodeAssignment`) unless there's a specified size, where that one should be preferred.

If I do

```
select * from Test..Cars c
left join Test..CodeAssignment a on c.Serial = a.Serial and c.Size = a.Size
```

I get the right `Code` but only for the entry that has the `Size` entry in the CodeAssignment table.

I tried appending it with a union where `c.Size` is null but it brings back two assignments for the `L x99` car...

I toyed with using CASE WHEN but figured that was only possible with hardcoded values and my problem is that this should be pulling conditionally from this 2nd table AND there'll be more than one conditional column to test against.

Is this possible using the current set up or how else could I set up the tables to do this type of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `left join`s:

```
select c.*, coalesce(ca.code, cad.code) as code
from cars c left join
     codeassignment ca
     on ca.serial = c.serial and ca.size = c.size left join
     codeassignment cad
     on cad.serial = c.serial and cad.size is null and ca.size is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f639960090fd99e3de0de8104a798271) is a db<>fiddle.

The first `left join` is for an exact match.  The second is for the default value if the first doesn't match.

Comment: That brings out four results but the codes are still NULL for those with no assignment rather than the default (e.g. 3000)

Comment: @jamheadart . . . I fixed it and provided a fiddle.